# What options are there for exposing a WCF service to multiple internal service consumers?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, api, dll, distribution

I have a WCF service to be used by multiple .NET consumers.

All development is done with VS2010, and although I currently have an application consuming the service, I don't like how VS2010 'helps' you connect to WCF services.

The problem that I'm having is that if you add a service reference in VS2010, it separates types on different endpoints into different namespaces even if they're the same type on the server.

Example:
I have a service with 3 endpoints:  end1, end2, end3
The endpoints all share a type my.server.type.SomeType

When I have VS2010 build service references for endpoints end1, end2, and end3 it creates proxy classes in different namespaces for SomeType

What options are there other than distributing a DLL (which I'm fine with)?  And if I do go down that road, should it be the minimal DLL of signatures and types, or abstract out more functionality into an API?

Mark

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved my using svcutil.exe and specify multiple endpoints it will give you a ton of warnings but the generated classes work and are common across endpoints.